Flutter slider button in left and right direction

How to drag or slide the button? So I could increment and decrement the counter
I am using container and stack. On drag, I see a clone of the button not only one. And look like no material on it.
class _DraggableButtonState extends State<DraggableButton> {
  Offset _position = Offset.zero; // Current position of the button

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _position = widget.initialPosition;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: _position.dx,
      child: Draggable(
        axis: Axis.horizontal,
        child: widget.child,
        feedback: Container(
          child: widget.child,
        ),
        onDragEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            _position = details.offset;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I don't want to use any library.


Could you also add the code that you implemented so far to achieve what you posted?

Slider(
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _value = newValue;
            });
          },
          min: -50.0,
          max: 50.0,
          divisions: 100,
          onChangeEnd: (newValue) {
            int roundedValue = newValue.round();
            setState(() {
              _value = roundedValue.toDouble();
            });
          },
        ),

